# Where can I find an analysis of the semantic overlap of English "to have" and "with"?

Tags: semantics, verbs, resource-request, prepositions, possession

For years I've understood via my native speaker intuition and my interest in languages and linguistics that the preposition "with" can carry the semantic meaning of the verb "to have".

- The man who has a big nose walks by.
- The man with the big nose walks by.

But today I'm bringing up this topic with others and wanted to point them to some material they can read rather than just take my word on it.

But my usually good Google skills are not finding anything at all. Perhaps because the two keywords are just too common and have too many meanings and uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My MA thesis in 1967 was about that.  It is ["The English preposition WITH"](https://linguistics.osu.edu/sites/linguistics.osu.edu/files/workingpapers/osu_wpl_01.pdf).